# Is it better to have object components in a variable than using GetComponent everytime? (Unity c#)

Tags: unity, c#

Is this:

```
Rigidbody2D rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

void Update()
{
    rb.AddForce(transform.up * 20 * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

Better than this?:

```
void Update()
{
    GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(transform.up * 20 * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

And can you please tell me why?

Comment: The first one only fetches the component once while the second one does it every frame - so the first one should be a bit more efficient **assuming the `Rigidbody2D` component is always present.** Neither of these two actually checks if the function call actually returned a valid component

Answer (score 3):

Yes, caching component references is good for performance. `GetComponent<>` involves a search through the object's components for the one you want, so if you already have a reference to it then you can skip the search.

But it doesn't work quite the way you've written it.

```
Rigidbody2D rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
```

As a field initializer, we're not allowed to reference non-static methods of the class we're constructing, so this will generate a compile error. (Generally, you should avoid doing much in these initializers in Unity - they run on a separate loading thread so they're limited in what they're allowed to touch)

Instead, you'd want to do this in `Start`, or optionally `Awake`/`OnEnable` if you need it sooner.

```
// If our code is going to assume there's an RB attached,
// let's make that assumption explicit so the editor can enforce it.
[RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody2D))]
public class MyPhysicsScript : MonoBehaviour {

    // Cache a reference to our attached Rigidbody on startup.
    Rigidbody2D _rb;

    void Start() {
        _rb = GetCoponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    // Physics code can now reference the Rigidbody without
    // repeatedly searching for it every frame.   
    void FixedUpdate() {
        // Code that uses _rb goes here.
    }
}
```